# Connect MongoDB to NodeJS on GAE

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine

I'm running a NodeJS app on GAE and I want to connect to a mongodb cluster on Atlas.

I have white-listed my IP on atlas and established a connection. All work fine on my local machine.

When deployed my app on GAE it could not connect to Atlas since the IP is not white-listed. When I white-listed all IPs on Atlas I could make a connection and everything worked fine as on my local machine

I cannot assign a static-IP to a standard GAE app, therefore I must allow access from anywhere to my cluster on Atlas, which is probably a bad idea.

What would be best solution to work with mongoDB from a GAE standard app?
Any configuration I can make to Atlas? maybe switching to mLab? or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

App Engine applications do not have fixed IP addresses. I'm not very familiar with MongoDB Atlas, but it does look like it offers an [option to run on GCP](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/mongodb-google-cloud?jmp=google-cl) and if that runs on a Compute Engine instance what you might be able to do is use the [VPC Connector](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/connecting-vpc) to enable access between your app and your MongoDB setup.